# Undo of delete in the database with exclude

Tags: python, django, django-models

I was solving a bug and I wrongly launch this piece of code

```
models.AACAreaTile.objects.exclude(id__in=keep_tiles_id).delete()
```

That it result in delete all that kind of object. Any way to undo this?

Comment: I don't think so. It is equivalent to delete in SQL.

Comment: @Dr. Mouse Can you provide a source to that? Not trying to start a fight or call you out, I am just wondering. Does delete() actually equal SQL delete?

Comment: @Krazor Sure ! It is described as _Issues an SQL DELETE for the object._ in the django docs : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.delete